# Find if a string contains substring with a number, some distance from another substring

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have a string like

```
s = 'ahlkhsa-anchorawO&B6o77ooiynlhwlkfnbla,)9;}[test:""ajanchorkh,2Yio98vacpoi [p{7}]test:"2"*iuyanchorap07A(p)a test:""*^g8p9JiguanchorLI;ntest:"9.3"'
```

i'd like to see if there exists a substring `test:"some_number_here"` that's at most 5 characters following `anchor`

So in this case there is, `test:"9.3"` is following substring `anchor` after 5 other character.

There is also `test:"2"` but it's too far away from the `anchor` before it, so I don't want to count it.

(Bonus points if i could pull out the number inside `test:""`)

Comment: Try [`anchor.{,5}test:"([\d.]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/YDj7ny/1), see more about [regex quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)

Comment: @HaoWu amazing :) Please post a comment so I can mark is as answer. Trying to figure out how to apply it directly.

Comment: Just did, see if it helps better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
anchor.{,5}test:"([\d.]+)"
```

```
anchor            // literally "anchor"
.{,5}             // any character, repeats up to 5 times
test:"([\d.]+)"   // test:"digits and dots", the digits and dots are captured in group 1
```

The number is captured in group 1, see the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/YDj7ny/1)

See more about [regex quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)

- Use it in Python:

```py
import re

s = 'ahlkhsa-anchorawO&B6o77ooiynlhwlkfnbla,)9;}[test:""ajanchorkh,2Yio98vacpoi [p{7}]test:"2"*iuyanchorap07A(p)a test:""*^g8p9JiguanchorLI;ntest:"9.3"'

res = re.findall(r'anchor.{,5}test:"([\d.]+)"', s)

print(res)  # ['9.3']
```

- Note

> The number matching is loose, `test:"."` also counts. If you want a more restricted number validation, you could try [`anchor.{,5}test:"(?!\.?")(\d*(?:\.\d*)?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/uP0817/1)